# Should I use exceptions for checking valid input?

Tags: c++, assert, c++20

I am using `gcc10.2`, `c++20`.

I am studying c++ after 2 years of python.

In python we always did run-time check for input validity

```
def createRectangle(x, y, width, height): # just for example
    for v in [x, y, width, height]:
        if v < 0:
            raise ValueError("Cant be negative")
    # blahblahblah
```

How would I do such process in c++?

Comment: `raise` equivalent is `throw`.

Comment: `if(v < 0) throw std::out_of_range("Cant be negative");`

Comment: C++ is a wrong typed language, use some `unsigned` type as arguments, so they cannot be negative :)

Comment: @Jarod42 - That is the best typo I have seen in a while.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Am I strong? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int v : {x, y, width, height})
    if (v < 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Can't be negative");
```

Note that such loop copies each variable twice. If your variables are heavy to copy (e.g. containers), use pointers instead:

```
for (const int *v : {&x, &y, &width, &height})
    if (*v < 0)
        ...
```

---

Comments also suggest using a reference, e.g. `for (const int &v : {x, y, width, height})`, but that will still give you one copy per variable. So if a type is that heavy, I'd prefer pointers.

Comment: This is not an assertation though. It's not clear what OP wants.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I decided to trust the question body more than the title. :)

Comment: *use pointers instead* Why??? `for (const auto& v : {x, y, width, height})`

Comment: I'm not sure about your "use pointers" bit.

Comment: @NathanOliver Variables will still be copied into the init list I think?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that'll do it.

Comment: @NathanOliver: `for (const auto& v : {std::cref(x), std::cref(y), std::cref(width), std::cref(height)})`.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: `auto&` only avoids one copy (by element), but `{x, y, width, height}` would be `std::initializer_list<Object>`, so a copy of each element.

Comment: @Jarod42 But is your version any better than using pointers as this answer proposes?

Comment: @Jarod42 I like the idea to not have to dereference the pointer. Perhaps `for (const decltype(x)& v : {std::cref(x), std::cref(y), std::cref(width), std::cref(height)})` to not get a reference_wrapper in `v` but to get it as the correct `const int&` (or whatever type it is)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo `*` to derefence is shorter to type than `std::cref` :-)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili :-) Hmm, you are correct :-D

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: I tend to check every pointer dereferencement as pointers might be `nullptr`, and using `if (!v || *v < 0)` seems not very good. (but indeed, here, I would use pointer without check as less wrong).

Answer (score 1):

In C++:

1. Use an appropriate type so validation (at the point you *use* the variables as opposed to setting them up from some input) is unnecessary, e.g. `unsigned` for a length. C++ is more strongly typed than Python, so you don't need large validation checks to make sure the correct type is passed to a function.
2. A `throw` is broadly equivalent to a `raise` in Python. In C++, we tend to derive an exception from `std::exception`, and throw that.

Boost ([www.boost.org](http://www.boost.org)) has a nice validation library which is well-worth looking at.

Comment: C++ doesn't have `unsigned double` though ;-) (Yes, I saw before the edit :-) )

Comment: I disagree with point 1. Using `unsigned` *hides* errors. If a user calls the function with a negative number, there's no good way of checking if they made a mistake.

Comment: @Jarod42: There's no hiding here, even with the 5 minute grace period.

Comment: @cigien: It only hides errors if you're having a senior moment when dealing with IO.

Comment: Taking an unsigned for size is a bad idea: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BkoEtG7Jy6qCmwqs.  You really shouldn't use it for must be positive values.

Comment: Some compiler might provide warning for implicit signed->unsigned conversion (Lot of noise most of the time :-/)

Comment: @NathanOliver: For me that's dogmatic. The arguments around `unsigned` types will rumble on until a language that replaces C++ emerges.

Comment: I saw the `operator >>` as "broken" in that regard...

Comment: So to clarify: your latest edit is suggesting that *every* caller of this function should now switch over to using `unsigned` so that they don't make a mistake while calling it? What about values that the calling code receives from other sources? It sounds like you're suggesting the entire program should switch over to `unsigned`. What about existing `signed` values that need to be signed, and interactions with them? I have to say this sounds like poor advice.

Comment: I agree that taking an `unsigned` is the most explicit way. If someone tries to pass an `int`, they *should* get a warning about the implicit conversion, which is better than a runtime exception.

Comment: @cigien callers should check for negative before calling, then add an explicit cast. It's like taking by reference instead of pointer so callers must check for null before calling.

Comment: @cigien [`gsl::narrow_cast`](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/main/include/gsl/util) ?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I'm fine with changing a function in a way that *forces* the caller to do something, but taking an `unsigned` parameter doesn't do that. At best, it gives a warning, and that can be ignored. Caleth's suggestion to use `gsl::narrow_cast` has the similar problem, in that the caller is not required to use it. My issue with this `unsigned` argument is that the function gets an illusion of safety that simply is not guaranteed.

Comment: @cigien: you might still have a `safe_unsigned_int` class with `delete` constructor from signed, and (explicit) constructor from unsigned :-)